# Is there a better way to organise javascript in a single file with specific code for multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of websites where I use a relatively small amount of jQuery to do various things on the pages. Generally we're talking about a couple of dozen lines of code per page.

I keep all of my JS in one file so far as it's not huge and fairly clearly defined. That said, what I have trended towards is organizing it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var onPage1 = $("#id_thing_on_1").length === 1;
  if( onPage1 ){
    var usefulPage1Function = function(){}; //blah
    $("a").click(function(){}); //etc
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  var onPage2 = $("#id_of_page_2").length === 1;
  if( onPage2 ){
    $(".someClass").fadeIn().click(function(){}); //etc
  }
});
```

Anything that *is* used on multiple pages gets taken out into a library, but for page specific stuff, this is the pattern I've been following. Is there a better approach, or is this an acceptable practice for keeping your JS in one file and loading it on multiple pages?

Comment: You probably just need one $(document).ready() unless if you have specific reason

Answer (score 3):

I would be interested in knowing other's view on this, but what I did so organize and execute the correct set of JS code for each page, is to have a kind of routing engine as the basis of my js app where I add a 'controller' list that each section adds it self to and the routing engine calls the controller.init() method based on the url.

```
myApp = {};

(function(app, $) {
    var defaultController = "Default";

    var routes = [];
    routes["Default"] = defaultController;

    var currentControllerFromUrl = function() {
        // match urls in the form ../mvc/controllerName.mvc/...
        var re = new RegExp(/\/(\w*)/i);
        var m = re.exec(document.location);
        if (m == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return m[1];
        }
    };

    var currentActionFromUrl = function() {
        // match urls in the form ../mvc/controllerName.mvc/action/
        var re = new RegExp(/\/mvc\/\w*.mvc\/(\w*)(\/|\b)/i);
        var m = re.exec(document.location);
        if (m == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return m[1].toLowerCase();
        }
    };

    var currentWebPageFromUrl = function() {
        var re = new RegExp(/\/(\w*).html/i);
        var m = re.exec(document.location);
        if (m == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return m[1];
        }
    };

    var populateControllerRoutes = function(app) {
        for (var ctl in app.controllers) {
            routes[ctl] = ctl;
        }
    };


    var theApp = {
        controllers: {},
        run: function() {
            this.initController();
        },
        initController: function() {
            var urlController = currentWebPageFromUrl();
            // populate routes
            populateControllerRoutes(this);
            if (urlController && routes[urlController]) {

                // load the correct controller into the activeController
                this.controller = new this.controllers[routes[urlController]]();
                this.controller.init();

                var action = currentActionFromUrl() || "index";
                if (action && this.controller[action + "Action"] !== undefined)
                    this.controller[action + "Action"]();

            }
        }

    };

    window.myApp = $.extend(app, theApp);
})(myApp || {}, jQuery);


// and somewhere else
(function($) {
    myApp.controllers.default = function() {
        this.init = function() {
        };

        this.indexAction = function() {
            // index action init
            $("#res").text("hi there!");
        }
    }
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    myApp.run();
});
```

With this approach, the controller functions don't need to be in one file, so during development you can keep your controller functions in separate files nicely organized and as part of the build/deploy, combine them and minimize them all into one JS file.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't think about including routing for xhr calls, but could be interesting, although most/all of the ajax calls would be originated inside a controller action with their own handlers, right? I guess if all the app is ajax based then you really get a nice routing though the global ajax handlers

Comment: I like this, I do a similar thing based of this article from Paul Irish http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/. Each controller has a separate .js file and they have init/ajaxInit funcions that are invoked by looking at the url of the loaded page (full page load or xhr call) - All forms are hooked up generically using the global jquery ajax handlers, it is a cool mvc layer in js. I also use the pubsub plugin to respond to actions. Any new controllers/actions require very little markup to fit into the pattern.

Comment: @Jamie - No all new form content (either html partials or generated template markup) are hooked up in the common namespace using the global ajax handlers. Each action can have a validation function that I try to call in the beforeSubmit, they can also have complete/success/error events if they need special handling that the common handlers cannot deal with. The common handlers do their stuff then try to call the method on the namespace for that url.

Comment: @redsquare - oooh, I get it... very nice way indeed... I think that's a good direction to take my little appBase to. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting idea. I'm wondering if it will be a pain when the URLs need to be changed -- two changes will need to be made, server code and javascript.

Comment: In this form yes, although using an idea from Paul Irish,you could get the name of the active controller from the Id of the body tag, that way you wouldn't need to change the routing code when changing the server routing. Another way could be to emit a routing table using your routing strategy from the server.

Comment: @Jaime I'd be very interested in what you come up with, perhaps we can collaborate on this mechanism further if you interested? Email on my profile.

Comment: I wouldn't think of it as pages, but as modules. The one thing I think YUI does right is their namespace philosophy. For example, start with `myApp.namespace("lib", "lib/modules")`, then add your modules within an anonymous function, and lastly test whether they exist in your `dom:loaded` event.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to reduce the redundancy in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function page1() {
    var usefulPage1Function = function(){}; //blah
    $("a").click(function(){}); //etc
  }

  function page2() {
    $(".someClass").fadeIn().click(function(){}); //etc
  }

  var pages = [
    [ '#id_thing_on_1', page1 ],
    [ '#id_of_page_2',  page2 ]
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
    if ($(pages[i][0]).length === 1)
      pages[i][1]();
});
```

Comment: I like this because later if you decide to call the javascript code per page directly from the html files you can just reference `page1()`, `page2()`, etc

Answer (score 0):

There is a cost for loading js you don't need. But really it depends on the usage pattern of your site. If the majority of the page loads occur on the homepage for instance, then merging and minifying *all* your js into one file for that page might make sense. If the unique code is kept small, then your approach is sound. This illustrates the natural tendency of code to loose structure when it is optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us why you want to put different page specific codes into the one single file, given the fact that you are 100% sure those codes won't be executed, in fact you are spending time to write up code/controller to avoid those unrelated code to be executed.

Also how many pages are you talking about, if it's only 2 pages, then you should be fine. But what if 50 pages? What if 20 pages use the same code, what your controller is going to look like? Or are you going to copy the same piece of code 20 times?

HOWEVER, having all codes in a minified single file does seem to load faster than browser initiating multiple downloads. You should have a balance between network VS coding practice.

I tend to have different js files with page specific code for different pages, so unrelated codes are not loaded.

Any code that is common use, I put it into specific lib js files, so most of the unrelated lib code are not loaded.

Eg.

```
Search page will have:
  search_page.js
  util.js  
  form_validation.js

Result page will have
  result_page.js
  util.js
  lib_map.js
```

Just my $0.02

Comment: There's a major implementation difference when referring to dependencies of the client-side versus server-side which is beyond the scope of this question.